# Unable to upload svg images

Tags: c#-4.0, svg, bitmap, multimedia

I am using the following code in my event system to upload svg Images. But this gives "Parameter is not valid error" when saving the image. The following is the code I am using. Is there anything I am missing?? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
//only for imagaes: svg
            if (mimeType.Contains("svg") && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            {
                messageLog.WriteEntry("OnComponentSavePre - resizing image - for component: " + comp.Title);

                // need to save first new component to be able to get type in next step
                if (args.IsNewItem)
                {
                    comp.Save();
                }

                BinaryContent bc = comp.BinaryContent;
                var objConvertor = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap));
                var bmpObj = (Bitmap)objConvertor.ConvertFrom(bc.GetByteArray());

                //reades multimedia fields
                ItemFields itemFields = new ItemFields(comp.Metadata, comp.MetadataSchema);

                if (itemFields.Contains("MM_Width"))
                {
                    NumberField width = itemFields["MM_Width"] as NumberField;
                    if (width != null && width.Value <= 0)
                    {
                        messageLog.WriteEntry("width = " + width.Value, EventLogEntryType.Information, 0, 0);
                        width.Value = bmpObj.Width;
                    }
                }

                if (itemFields.Contains("MM_Height"))
                {
                    NumberField height = itemFields["MM_Height"] as NumberField;
                    if (height != null && height.Value <= 0)
                    {
                        messageLog.WriteEntry("width = " + height.Value, EventLogEntryType.Information, 0, 0);
                        height.Value = bmpObj.Height;
                    }
                }
                comp.Metadata = itemFields.ToXml();
                messageLog.WriteEntry("metadata updated", EventLogEntryType.Information, 0, 0);
            }
```